# What is CSC Fastboot Mode, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: rooting, fastboot, csc

I am trying to access my Zenfone Go's fastboot in order to unlock its bootloader, but it seems to have been replaced with something called "CSC Fastboot mode".

In this mode, I just see the ASUS logo, a "CSC Fastboot Mode!" text, and I am unable to enter any input. It looks like this:

[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fGvKbRoB8b0/maxresdefault.jpg]

Since I cannot enter any input, most communication with fastboot.exe is impossible. I somehow managed to have fastboot.exe correctly detect the device, but any command that requires confirmation on the phone is impossible (ex: fastboot flashing unlock), fastboot.exe just waits forever. I tried inputting the commands on the phone anyway, in case there was an invisible menu or something, but didn't work.

What I tried:

- Turning off my phone, then "Power Button + Volume Up Button" until it restarts. It goes directly to CSC Fastboot Mode.
- Turning off my phone, then "Power Button + Volume Down Button" until it restarts. It goes into Recovery Mode. Then I select "reboot to bootloader". It goes to CSC Fastboot Mode.
- Accessing my phone through adb, and using the "reboot-bootloader" command. It goes to CSC Fastboot Mode.

What is CSC Fastboot mode? What is it caused by? And how to reach a usable fastboot menu?

**Model Number:** ASUS_X013DB

**Android Version:** 5.1.1

**Build Number:** LMY47V.JP_Phone-13.0209.1705.116-20170621044040677_2015122901270020000400001

Comment: Have you considered [a simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="CSC+Fastboot+mode")?

Comment: Do you have st least installed drivers? What is the output of fastboot devices ? Many phone have such screen while in fastboot mode. Your computer should detect it normally.

Comment: @Izzy I did spend the whole day on it, and read every single link on the first two pages on every search I could think of, so yes. Most of them are about how to reach CSC Fastboot Mode. A couple are about what to do once a phone doesn't reach anything else but CSC Fastboot Mode. There are some posts in Japanese and Malay, but from what I understand it was mostly people who booted in CSC Fastboot by accident. This question is already on the frontpage for CSC Fastboot searches, so I would say there is not a wealth of useful results

Comment: @esQmo_ I have installed drivers, yes. "fastboot devices" returns "G5AXGV51A2695PV fastboot". "fastboot flashing unlock" just displays "..." and stays stuck there

Comment: @Cristol.GdM the description on [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGvKbRoB8b0) (hit #1 when I click my above link) reads: "… How to use CSC Fastboot Mode? **How to Quit CSC Fasboot Mode in ASUS ZenFone Live?"** (emphasis mine) Wouldn't that match your needs? Maybe I've misinterpreted your question of "getting rid" – but in that case: I doubt you can "remove" it.

Comment: @Izzy I see, sorry I was a bit snappy above... I meant "getting rid of it" as in "getting access to a proper fastboot mode". I am trying to unlock my bootloader, which apparently requires me to input some confirmation to fastboot commands, but this CSC Fastboot mode is completely unresponsive

Comment: This phone requires an app to do the bootloader unlock stuffs, the app os made by asus

Comment: @esQmo_ Unfortunately this model doesn't seem to have an official unlocking app, unlike the other Zenfone models. At that point, I guess I will have to accept that it's one of the few unrootable phones :/

Answer (score -1):

1. Install ADB and Fastboot tools in your PC (two tools as parts of Android Studio)
2. Connect device through USB and open terminal/command prompt.
3. In terminal/command prompt, type:

   ```
   fastboot devices
   fastboot continue
   fastboot reboot
   ```

Comment: The question isn't how to reboot out of fastboot mode, it's how to confirm the `fastboot flashing unlock` operation on the phone.