# Asus Zenfone Max Pro (M2) forced into CSC Fastboot Mode

Tags: fastboot

I have Asus Zenfone Max Pro (M2) running on Android 8.1 Oreo and it was working fine, no viruses, no malware. When I was playing a game on the phone, I put it on the side, then I went to play a game on my PC. When I came back to my phone, it was turned off although it had plenty of battery left. When I tried to turn it back on, it launched into "CSC Fastboot Mode" and it will not boot normally anymore.

I have not rooted my phone either or even tampered with it. Currently, it's plugged in on the PC and in recovery mode. While the phone doesn't boot into Android, it does boot into recovery when pressing down on launch. When it's plugged in (when turned off) on the PC or in a wall plug, it turns on by itself.

I've already been searching for some similar options, but the closest post to the problem of mine was not solved or I think so:
[What is CSC Fastboot Mode, and how to get rid of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187159/what-is-csc-fastboot-mode-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

Comment: maybe it is a hardware issue with the physical buttons. not sure if it works with locked bootloader but you can download boot.img and try to boot from fastboot with `fastboot boot boot.img` https://skyfileos.com/2019/02/20/asus-zenfone-max-pro-m2-zb631kl-official-stock-firmware-update-rom

Comment: another workaround is open the device and disconnect the Volume buttons